# Laravel blade view not working, working without blade

Tags: php, laravel, view, routes, laravel-blade

I cannot get laravel blade view to work, removing the blade from file name makes it work. I am using laravel  5.2.22.

Here are the details:

Here is the route:

```
Route::get('/', function ()    {
  return view('login2');
});
```

Location and file name of 'login2': /resources/views/login2.blade.php

Inside of login2.blade.php:

```
<?php
echo "a";
```

As soon as I change the "login2.blade.php" -> "login2.php" it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: I forgot to mention that with blade template I get HTTP ERROR 500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed rights for folder `storage` to 777 and now blade views work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to close tag:

```
<?php echo "a"; ?>
```

Blade template files are parsed with a template engine, so you need to close tag if you're using raw PHP inside a template.

Comment: Nop. Still no luck. I forgot to mention that with blade template I get HTTP ERROR 500.

Comment: If you're getting 500 error, the problem is not in a view, but in web server config or permissions.